# Segue between two tabbarcontrollers

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

We have redesigned our application to use a Tabbarcontroller as the main view.  There is one instance where we need to display a record with enough data that it's also broken out into a tabbarcontroller.  Previously we did our segue as showing below.  I'm not sure what needs to change to segue between two tabbarcontrollers

```
SelectProvidersView *view = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"careTeamView"];
view.careProviders = self.selectedPatient.careProviders;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

I'm guessing it's because I'm inside a tab controller instead of a navigation controller, I just don't know how this should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `segue` to switch between `tabBarControllers`. Use `[(UITabBarController*)self.navigationController.topViewController setSelectedIndex:index];` to manually switch to the `viewController` you want

Comment: That will swap out all my tabs for the new tabs?  Will I still be able to use the back button functionality?

Comment: You also need to use the function above to switch back